# Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I ran the following from the book Hyperledger Cookbook pg 37:

```
sudo fabric-samples/fabcar/startFabric.sh node
```

and received the following error:

```
# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
Stopping couchdb ... done
Stopping orderer.example.com ... done
Stopping ca.example.com ... done
Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Removing couchdb ... done
Removing orderer.example.com ... done
Removing ca.example.com ... done
Removing network net_basic

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
Creating network "net_basic" with the default driver
Creating ca.example.com
Creating orderer.example.com
Creating couchdb
Creating peer0.org1.example.com

# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
#echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
2021-01-21 09:39:45.529 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2021-01-21 09:39:45.724 UTC [cli/common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Received block: 0
# Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
2021-01-21 09:39:46.913 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing)
```

Can someone point me to what I should look at to understand the error and possible fix?

Answer (score 0):

Either your peer or orderer is not setup correctly.

Try to check there status and logs using

```
docker ps -a
```

to see the logs

```
docker logs -f <containerId/name>
```

Comment: peer node start exited with error: [couchdb] CreateCouchDatabase -> ERRO 029 Error calling CouchDB CreateDatabaseIfNotExist() for dbName: mychannel_, error: error decoding response body: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field DBInfo.purge_seq of type int. What does this mean?

Comment: if you are running this on windows, then I suggest you to run it on ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah, ran it on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: try to run without using the CouchDB

Comment: fabric-samples.first-network/byfn.sh up -c mychannel runs fine without couchdb, but when fabric-samples.first-network/byfn.sh up -c mychannel -s couchdb, it produces similar error. I looked at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/couchdb_tutorial.html but no idea where to find FABRIC_CFG_PATH.

Comment: FABRIC_CFG_PATH is the path to your configtx.yaml file. 
like export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}. I thing the error is because you are inside wrong directory. you need to run the commands from first-network directory

Comment: fabric-samples/first-network/byfn.sh up. Yeah I ran from the first-network directory.

Comment: Btw I found core.yaml file and added stateDatabase: CouchDB and it didn't fix it.

Comment: Installing fabric 1.4.4 instead of 1.3.0 resolved the issue. https://forum.linuxfoundation.org/discussion/856408/lab3-error-failed-sending-proposal-got-rpc-error-code-unavailable-desc-transport-is-closing. Thanks for help anyway.